# Unable to complete fourier analysis in wolfram-mathmetica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

Firstly:
I am a complete noob so apologies for the terrible formatting.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://blog.wolfram.com/2013/05/17/making-formulas-for-everything-from-pi-to-the-pink-panther-to-sir-isaac-newton/) to get the fourier series of an image. I keep running into errors with this section of code midway through the tutorial:

```
(* Fourier coefficients of a single curve *)
    fourierComponentData[pointList_, nMax_, op_] := 
     Module[{\[CurlyEpsilon] = 10^-3, \[Mu] = 2^14, M = 10000, s,
                    scale, \[CapitalDelta], L , nds, sMax, 
       if, \[ScriptX]\[ScriptY]Function, X, Y, XFT, YFT, type},
      (* prepare curve *)
      scale = 
       1. Mean[Table[ 
          Max[ fl /@ pointList] - 
           Min[fl /@ pointList], {fl, {First, Last}}]];
       \[CapitalDelta] = 
       EuclideanDistance[First[pointList], Last[pointList]];
       L = Which[op === "Closed", type = "Closed";
                                                                
        If[First[pointList] === Last[pointList], 
                                                                    
         pointList, Append[pointList, First[pointList]]], 
                        op === "Open", type = "Open"; pointList,
                         \[CapitalDelta] == 0., type = "Closed";  
        pointList,
                         \[CapitalDelta]/scale < op, type = "Closed"; 
        Append[pointList, First[pointList]],
                        True,  type = "Open"; 
        Join[pointList, Rest[Reverse[pointList]]]];
      (* re-parametrize curve by arclength *)
      \[ScriptX]\[ScriptY]Function = BSplineFunction[L, SplineDegree -> 4];
      nds = NDSolve[{s'[t] == 
          Sqrt[\[ScriptX]\[ScriptY]Function'[
             t].\[ScriptX]\[ScriptY]Function'[t]], s[0] == 0}, s, 
                                  {t, 0, 1}, MaxSteps -> 10^5, 
        PrecisionGoal -> 4];
      (* total curve length *)
           sMax = s[1] /. nds[[1]];
           if = 
       Interpolation[
        Table[{s[\[Sigma]] /. nds[[1]], \[Sigma]}, {\[Sigma], 0, 1, 1/M}]];
      X[t_Real] :=  
       BSplineFunction[L][Max[Min[1, if[(t + Pi)/(2 Pi) sMax]] , 0]][[1]];
      Y[t_Real] :=  
       BSplineFunction[L][Max[Min[1, if[(t + Pi)/(2 Pi) sMax]] , 0]][[2]]; 
      (* extract Fourier coefficients *)
      {XFT, YFT} = 
       Fourier[Table[#[N @ t], {t, -Pi + \[CurlyEpsilon], 
            Pi - \[CurlyEpsilon], (2 Pi - 
               2 \[CurlyEpsilon])/\[Mu]}]] & /@ {X, Y};   
      {type, 2 Pi/Sqrt[\[Mu]] *
        ((Transpose[
             Table[{Re[#], Im[#]} &[Exp[I k Pi]  #[[k + 1]]], {k, 0, 
               nMax}]] & /@ {XFT, YFT}))}  ]
    
        Options[fourierComponents] = {"MaxOrder" -> 180, "OpenClose" -> 0.025};
    
    fourierComponents[pointLists_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
     Monitor[Table[
        fourierComponentData[pointLists[[k]],                           
                                                                          \
         If[Head[#] === List, #[[k]], #] &[ OptionValue["MaxOrder"]],
                                                                          \
         If[Head[#] === List, #[[k]], #] &[ OptionValue["OpenClose"]]],
                                 {k, Length[pointLists]}],
       Grid[{{Text[
           Style["progress calculating Fourier coefficients", 
            Darker[Green, 0.66]]], 
          ProgressIndicator[k/Length[pointLists]]} }, 
                Alignment -> Left, Dividers -> Center]] /; 
      Depth[pointLists] === 4
    
        fCs = fourierComponents[hLines, 
       "OpenClose" -> Table["Closed", {Length[hLines]}]];
```

the stack trace is:

[image]

any help is much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and it is exactly the same as in the tutorial.

Please check code published to the Wolfram Cloud:

https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/dg356172/Published/Fourier%20Transform%20Image.nb

It works for me.

You can have problems in steps when `hLines` is defined.

Comment: thanks for the help, I think I get a different number of hlines than the tutorial so that must be the issue

Comment: I had also problems with defining `hLines`. There are many steps and enough to skip a single step to broke calculations. But in the original tutorial, were 11 `hLines`, in my code there is 9 and it works.